# Prompt() Login trouble

Tags: javascript, loops, authentication

I'm trying to make a login for a site and I'm having trouble with the while loop.
 It goes through correctly if I type in the right logins but if I get it wrong, it doesn't repeat. Since the variable, "login", is still false, I don't know why the while loop won't run again.

```
var login = false;
var num = 0;
var username = prompt("Enter your username");
var password = prompt("Enter your password");
while(!login){
    if(username == users[num].name){
        if(password == users[num].password){
            alert("welcome");
            login = true;
        }
    }
    if(num >= users.length){
        alert("incorrect login");
        num = 0;
        username = prompt("Enter your username");
        password = prompt("Enter your password");
    } else {
        num++
    }
}
```

Comment: In your piece of code, `users` is not defined

Comment: Looks like you are missing a users object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets decompose the problem a little to first have a validity check for a login...

```
// assumes users is an array of registered users
function loginIsValid(username, password) {
    for (var n=0; n<users.length; n++) {
        if(username === users[n].name && password == users[n].password)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now our prompt loop is simpler...

```
var login = false;
while(!login){
    var username = prompt("Enter your username");
    var password = prompt("Enter your password");
    if (loginIsValid(username, password)) login = true;
}
```

You could consider adding a counter, so the check is:

```
 var attempts = 0;
 while(!login && attempts < MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
     attempts += 1;
     // etc
```